# Group and calculate sum with joined table

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have `table1` like this:

```
ID uid jid type val
1   1   1   1   1
2   1   1   1   10
3   1   2   1   100
4   1   3   1   1000
5   1   4   2   2
```

And joined `table2`:

```
ID uid jid stat time
1   1   1   1   100
2   1   1   1   200
3   1   1   4   300
4   1   2   2   400
```

I try to get SUM of val from table1, group it by uid and type and join table2 by this query:

```
SELECT a.uid, a.type, SUM(a.val) as t1, SUM(a.val)*COUNT(distinct(a.id))/COUNT(a.id) as t2, MAX(b.time) as max_time
FROM table1 as a
LEFT JOIN table2 as b on b.uid = a.uid and b.jid = a.jid and b.stat = 1
GROUP BY a.uid, a.type
```

In result I get this values:

```
uid type t1     t2     max_time
1   1   1122  748.0000  200
1   2      2    2.0000  NULL
```

But total for type=1 should be: `1111` (not 1122 and not 748)

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You need use DISTINCT with a.uid in select statement. corrected query is below:

SELECT DISTINCT(a.uid), a.type, SUM(a.val) AS t1, SUM(a.val)*COUNT(DISTINCT(a.id))/COUNT(a.id) AS t2, MAX(b.time) AS max_time
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON b.uid = a.uid AND b.jid = a.jid AND b.stat = 1
GROUP BY a.uid, a.type

Comment: Sorry, but not. As is I group by a.uid it will be always different in selection.

Comment: sorry my mistake updated solution:

SELECT auid, atype, SUM(aval)
, SUM(aval)*COUNT(DISTINCT(aid))/COUNT(aid) AS t2, MAX(btime) AS max_time
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT(a.uid) AS auid, a.type AS atype, a.val AS aval, a.id AS aid, b.time AS btime
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON b.uid = a.uid AND b.jid = a.jid AND b.stat = 1
) AS grouptable
GROUP BY auid, atype

Comment: This give same response as my query.

Comment: This gives me result:


------------------------------------------------------------
auid atype SUM(aval) t2                 max_time
1 1         1111                 1111.0000 0000-00-00 00:00:00
1 2         2           2.0000  (NULL)


--------------------------------
isn't is this you are looking at.

Comment: I think you not fully add values to table2. This join give issues

Answer (score 0):

can you recheck the sql:

SELECT auid, atype, SUM(aval)
, SUM(aval)*COUNT(DISTINCT(aid))/COUNT(aid) AS t2, MAX(btime) AS max_time
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT(a.uid) AS auid, a.type AS atype, a.val AS aval, a.id AS aid, b.time AS btime
FROM table1 AS a
LEFT JOIN table2 AS b ON b.uid = a.uid AND b.jid = a.jid AND b.stat = 1
) AS grouptable
GROUP BY auid, atype

Output I got:

auid  atype  sum(aval)   t2             max_time

1      1         1111          1111.0000   200

1      2         2                2.0000      (NULL)

Is the result you are looking for?

Comment: Here what I get screencast.com/t/QQ4Fimwu71x 
I think you not fully add values to table2. This join give issues      
 
screencast.com/t/6CYsY8w0fn